# How to decompile an assembly without considering the additional dependencies in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, .net-assembly

Here is my code, what I want to achieve is to decompile the assembly. However, when I starting to do this, it throws an exception

> `Failed to resolve assembly: 'ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit, Version=5.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cc39be672370310'`

I guess that means the decompiler cannot find the **additional dependencies** for that assembly. So, is there any method to just skip finding the additional dependencies but just decompile the code? Or if there is any way I can put the additional dependencies into the decompile process? Please help！

```
foreach(var types in myASB.MainModule.Types)
{
    Console.WriteLine(types.Name);
    AstBuilder astBuilder = new AstBuilder(new DecompilerContext(myASB.MainModule)
    {
        CurrentType = types,
    });

    astBuilder.AddType(types);
    var writeText = new PlainTextOutput();

    astBuilder.GenerateCode(writeText);
    Files.WriteFileContent(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Code", Files.getSafeFileNameString(types.Name) + ".cs"), writeText.ToString());

}
```